# Image upload and preview using Javascript function not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, image-upload

The below coding in Javascript for uploading image and preview works fine in chrome but not working in IE8. I tried the whole day, but I cant solve this. Anyone can help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

```
<form name="addpoll" action="" method="post" id="addpoll" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="polladdform" onsubmit="return validation();">

    <input type="button" onclick="HandFileButtonClick();"  value="Browse" id="firstremove" style="margin-top: 30px;" class="addmultiple">

    <input type=file name="choiceimg1" id="chimg1" value ="Select"  onchange="readURL(this)" style="display:none;">

    <img src="#" name="viewimg1" class="addmultiple" id="viewimg1" height="70px" width="85px" style="display:none"/>


<script>
function HandFileButtonClick()

  {

    document.addpoll.choiceimg1.click();

  }
function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                    var ss=$(input).attr('name');

                    var n=ss.split("choiceimg");
                reader.onload = function (e) {

                    $('#viewimg'+n[1]).css({'display':'block','margin-left':'332px','margin-top':'-88px'});

                    $('#viewimg'+n[1]).attr('src', e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: `FileReader` in ie8, r u kidding?

Comment: That's why im asking any other function with same functionality for FileReader for the above coding

Comment: Then you need to rephrase your question I guess. And remove all the blah-blah-blah about 'I tried the whole day, but I cant solve this.'

Comment: Older or non modern browsers (IE is great example) do not support File API of JavaScript. Only way to read files with JavaScript on IE is by using the unsafe ActiveX "Scripting.FileSystemObject" however user will first have to  allow you permission and unless it's internal network, that just won't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft provided an object to handle file, `FileSystemObject`, doc is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z9ffy99%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

It does can get file content correctly, but there're two limitations that make it useless in most situation:

- "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe" must be "Enable";
- "Include local directory path when uploading files to a server" must be "Enable".

Those two options are in IE's security setting, I don't think user will make them as "Enable" in normal situation.